# Add a scrollbar to a dynamic view

Tags: android, scrollbar

I have a LinearLayout and I amdynamically creating a certain number of TextViews in it.
Sometimes there are more TextViews than fit on the screen.

How do I add a scrollbar to this view, so the user can scroll up and down and see all TextViews?

Here's part of my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
for (int n = 0; n < (numberOfPlayers*(numberOfPlayers-1)/2); n++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(gamelist[n][0] + " - " + gamelist[n][1]);
    layout.addView(tv);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your linearLayout in a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/scroll"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout ... />

</ScrollView>
```

Note that a ScrollView can only have one view child

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `LinearLayout` into a `ScrollView`.

In this case you may consider using a `ListView` (tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)).